# How would I iterate onto the next line of a file within a nested loop using "for line" in fileinput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

**I have eliminated some of the nested loops for simplicity of the example.**

I am iterating over a file line-by-line using `fileinput`. If the line meets a certain condition I want it to replace all future lines with '' until it meets the condition again.

```
import re
import fileinput
with fileinput.FileInput("survey.qsf", inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        if re.match(r'l'+datamap[i][2]+'.*$',line)!=None:
            line=re.sub(r'.*$','',line)
            while re.match(r'lQID\d*$',line)==None:
                line=re.sub(r'.*$','',line)
                next(line)
```

I used "next(line)" as a placeholder as I can't figure out how to iterate to the next line without breaking out of the inner loop.

I want to be able to iterate through the lines to have:

```
lQID44
xyz
xyz
lQID45
```

output as:

```
[blank line]
[blank line]
[blank line]
lQID45
```

Thanks.

Comment: 1st: i'd simply set a boolean variable to true or false when matching occurs and replace lines dependent on this variable. No nested loops. 2nd: i'd use `str.startswith` rather than `re`, as imo that would suit here too. However, perhaps i just didn't get the complicated point here....

Comment: `next(file)` gives you the next line of the iterator. Beware that using it like this can lead to a `StopIteration` exception, if there is no next line, so maybe you should guard your call of `next` with a try-except-block, if you cannot make sure that there will always be a next line.

Comment: I didn't know about str.startswith I just got into the habit of using re. Yeah I am finding that iterating with next(file) leads to a StopIteration exception I'll catch that and then it should work. Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`next` takes the *iterator* as its argument.

```
while re.match(r'lQID\d*$',line)==None:
    line=re.sub(r'.*$','',line)
    try:
        line = next(file)  # Not next(line)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

As an aside, there's no need to use `re.sub` to replace the entire line with an empty string; `line = ''` would suffice.

(Also, assigning to `line` doesn't make changes to the actual file; `inplace=True` just means that you can *write* to `file` as well as read from it, but you have to explicitly write to the file, using `print` or `file.write`.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I think that "next()" might have a slight issue iterating fileinput because I get a StopIIteration error even though it isn't the last line when next(file) is used. Thanks for the other explanations though as this project is bigger than I had anticipated and my programming needs some finesse!

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need to reassign its return value to `line` so that you are checking the new line, rather than the same previous line over and over again. But it is true that calling `next` explicitly requires you to catch `StopIteration` your self when you do reach the end of the file, unlike the `for` loop which catches it for you (in addition to calling `next` for you implicitly).

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again mate. Thanks for simplifying my code whilst you were at it!